# Fine-Uploader ASP.NET Web Forms Server Side GET instead of POST

Tags: asp.net, fine-uploader

I have a previous implementation of Fine-Uploader 4.1 that works with ASP.NET Web Forms.

The server-side processing, in particular the initial request to the server,had been previously designed to work with receiving an initial POST, Which worked.

However, I have a new project, using 4.3, but the initial request server-side is sent as a GET.

I cannot seem to find where I would set or determine that I want Fine-Uploader to use a POST instead of a GET, for what I believe is the initial contact with the server to receive the signed signature.

I have compared both projects, have switched between 4.1 and 4.3, for the life of me I cannot figure out how Fine-Uploader is for the first project sending a POST, but for the second is sending a GET.
The client side code is almost exactly identical, the options for Fine-Uploader are the same for both projects.
Would this have to do with a `web.config` httpHandler verb setting?  I have changed those, but still a GET is sent instead of a POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader only sends GET requests in two instances:

1. When the uploader is constructed, if you have the [initial file list feature enabled](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html).
2. If you are using [Fine Uploader Azure](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/azure.html), GET requests are sent to retrieve signatures before sending requests to Azure.

Comment: FYI small typo on initial file list doc page, 'sestion'.